# How to improve Training and Test accuracy

Tags: image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

I am pretty new to Deep learning. I was experimenting with fine tuning of pretrained models on my own dataset but I am not able to improve the test and training accuracy. Both the Losses are hovering around 62 from beginning of training to last. I am using Xception as the pretrained model and combined with  GlobalAveragePooling2D, a dense layer and dropout of 0.2.

The dataset consists of 3522 images belonging to 2 class of training and 881 images belonging to 2 classes of test set. Problem is I am not able add any more images to the datasets. This is the maximum number of images I could add to the datasets. Tried ImageDataGenerator but still it's of no use. Images of two classes looks bit similar in this constraint can I increase the accuracy.

```
Code:
base_model = Xception(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
predictions = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
num_training_img=3522
num_test_img=881
stepsPerEpoch = num_training_img/batch_size
validationSteps= num_test_img/batch_size
history= model.fit_generator(
        train_data_gen,
        steps_per_epoch=stepsPerEpoch,
        epochs=20,
        validation_data = test_data_gen,
        validation_steps=validationSteps
        )
layer_num = len(model.layers)
for layer in model.layers[:129]:
    layer.trainable = False

for layer in model.layers[129:]:
    layer.trainable = True

    # update the weights
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
num_training_img=3522
num_test_img=881
stepsPerEpoch = num_training_img/batch_size
validationSteps= num_test_img/batch_size
history= model.fit_generator(
        train_data_gen,
        steps_per_epoch=stepsPerEpoch,
        epochs=20,
        validation_data = test_data_gen,
        validation_steps=validationSteps
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the layers non-trainable before creating the model.

```
base_model = Xception(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
```

Your last layer has 2 units, which suggests, softmax is a better fit.

`predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)`

Try with Adam and change loss.

`model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`